# How to use another sites returned html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 3rd party that returns a string of html. Lets call it 'b.com'.
I want to manipulate this string client side with java-script/jquery.
I want to do this on 'A.com'.

I am familiar with JSON being returned and being used server side, but never client side and never with html.

Could someone please assist?

I've tried this with jquery:

```
<body>
   <div id="temp"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#temp').load("http://www.b.com/datapage");
   </script>`enter code here`
</body>
```

And this with pure JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function httpGet(theUrl)
   {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false );
      xmlhttp.send();    
  }
  document.write(httpGet("http://stackoverflow.com/"));
</script>
```

Comment: Does `b.com` allow cross-origin requests ? What do you want to "manipulate" ? Can you include `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: Yes b.com does allow cross-origin requests.
The string of html is a table. i want to add more columns; Which will be easy enough once i have the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes b.com does allow cross-origin requests

Use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) , perform processing of `responseText` at [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then)

```
$.ajax({url:"b.com", type:"GET", dataType:"html", crossDomain:true})
.then(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  // do stuff with data here
}, function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
})
```

Comment: how would i do this with AJAX?
Ive tried:
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'HTML',
    url: b.com,
    crossDomain : true,
})